# Output foreach-item in <div>, but output every 2nd and 3rd item in wrapping div

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array with items: `$array = ['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4','item 5','item 6','item 7']`

I am looking for the following HTML:

```
<div class="big">Item 1</div>
<div>
    <div class="small">Item 2</div>
    <div class="small">Item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="big">Item 4</div>
<div>
    <div class="small">Item 5</div>
    <div class="small">Item 6</div>
</div>
<div class="big">Item 7</div>
```

In text: Every 3rd item (including the first) have to have their own `div`, while the 2nd and 3rd items get a wrapping `div`.

I've come up with the following loop, but I'm pretty sure it's not going to work in the long run, since it'll probably end the loop with an opening `div`, since I keep on opening a new one after each BIG ITEM.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $item) {
    <?php
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        if($i == 0) {?>
            <div class="big">
                Item <?= $i; ?>
                
            </div>
            <div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            </div>
            <div class="big">
                Item <?= $i; ?>
            </div>
            <div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="small">
            small item
            <?= $i; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php 
    $i++;
}
```

I feel like I'm close, but it also feels wrong to start and close divs in `$i`s where it doesn't belong. Maybe the only thing I'm missing is checking if `$i` equals the length of the array, and then don't open a new `<div>` after a big item?

Comment: Just for fun, depending on what you are doing, it is possible you might be able to handle whatever you need to do in CSS instead of structurally in HTML: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/zYWKmgM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple if-elseif-else construct to print the divs.

- If the index of the current element % 3 is 0, it is a `big` div, else it is a small div.
- If the index of the current element % 3 is greater than 0, it is a `small` div.

  - If it is 1, prepend an opening div tag.
  - If it is 2, append a closing div tag.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

foreach ($array as $idx => $set) {
    $mod = $idx % 3;
    if($mod === 0){
        echo "<div class='big'>$set</div>";
    }elseif($mod === 1){
        echo "<div><div class='small'>$set</div>";
    }else{// if $mod is 2
        echo "<div class='small'>$set</div></div>";
    }
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/87115)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use array_chunk then pick out the first item with array_shift, then join the remaining.

```
<?php
$array = array_chunk(['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4','item 5','item 6','item 7'], 3);

foreach ($array as $set) {
    echo '<div class="big">'.array_shift($set).'</div>';
    if (count($set)) echo '<div><div class="small">'.implode('</div><div class="small">', $set).'</div></div>';
}
?>
```

Result

```
<div class="big">item 1</div>
<div>
    <div class="small">item 2</div>
    <div class="small">item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="big">item 4</div>
<div>
    <div class="small">item 5</div>
    <div class="small">item 6</div>
</div>
<div class="big">item 7</div>
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/URB3D

Comment: I think I prefer this over the others because if the data gets weird, this one won’t end up with missing close tags.

Comment: @ChrisHaas OP would need to mention explicitly about any non-uniformity in the data set.

Comment: @nice_dev, although I agree, that's also why I like this solution since it does handle unexpected data a little better. Adding an eighth item does result in an edge case where the small grouping only has a single item, which the OP may or may not have accounted for, but at least the tags are balanced.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are my simple answer: I think you don't need to use additional counter in case that interpreter adds indexes to array:

```
$array = ['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4','item 5','item 6','item 7'];
foreach($array as $key=>$da){
$a = $key % 3;
if($a === 0){
    echo "<div class=\"big\">" . $da . "</div>\n";
} 
else{
    if($a === 1)
        echo "<div>\n";
    echo "    <div class=\"small\">" . $da . "</div>\n";
    if($a === 2)
        echo "<div>\n";
}
```

}